# undefined method eager_autoload when trying to start rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**UPDATE:** I fixed the error by installing rack-cache gem

I was trying to start a rails server on one of my project and got this error

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:105: warning: already initialized constant NEVER_UNPERMITTED_PARAMS
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:105: warning: already initialized constant NEVER_UNPERMITTED_PARAMS
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-action_caching-1.1.0/lib/action_controller/action_caching.rb:3:in `<module:Caching>': undefined method `eager_autoload' for ActionController::Caching:Module (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-action_caching-1.1.0/lib/action_controller/action_caching.rb:2:in `<module:ActionController>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-action_caching-1.1.0/lib/action_controller/action_caching.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-action_caching-1.1.0/lib/actionpack/action_caching.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `rescue in block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from /vagrant/captiv8/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I tried to reinstall the actionpack gem but the problem still persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try command "bundle exec rails server"

Comment: I fixed it by installing rack-cache gem. anyway thanks for answering.